# react native maps remove markers

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I've used react-native-maps in my project. It was working fine. then I added some new components to project, suddenly when I remove custom markers from map, red screen appears:
remove marker: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.model.setIcon(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescription)' on a null object reference
[image]

Comment: Do you provide a `key` to your markers ? Also, in your map component `render`, do you test for data availability before rendering your markers, returning `null` if no data is available ?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

**First option 
(the easiest but will not give you the best results)**

Use the default marker:

```
<MapView.Marker
                identifier="DestMarker"
                title={SCHEDULED_LABEL}
                description={this.props.region.address}
                coordinate={{
                    latitude: this.props.region.latitude,
                    longitude: this.props.region.longitude,
                }}
            />
```

**Second option
edit react-native-maps library**

go to:

> *lib/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/maps/AirMapMarker.java*

inside *node_modules* and change this line of code

`marker.setIcon(getIcon());`

for this:

```
if (marker != null) {
  marker.setIcon(getIcon());
}
```

and your done!

**Note: Remember to reinstall the app to see your changes**

Comment: This looks way too complicated.